# By proposition 3.21 is ether acute, right or obtuse

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, axioms

Let A, B, C be points on a line with A ∗ B ∗ C. Let D be a point not on that line such

that angle ABD is obtuse. Show that angle CBD is acute. Do NOT use the Measurement Theorem. (Hint: By Proposition 3.21, angle CBD is either acute, right, or obtuse. Consider the cases when it’s right and obtuse separately, obtaining a contradiction with
the hypothesis that angle ABD is obtuse in each case.)

for axioms http://math.gcsu.edu/~ryan/4510/notes/congruence.pdf

proposition 3.21

a. Exactly one of the following conditions holds (trichotomy): ∠P < ∠Q, ∠P ∼= ∠Q, or ∠P > ∠Q.

b. If ∠P < ∠Q and ∠Q ∼= ∠R, then ∠P < ∠R.

c. If ∠P > ∠Q and ∠Q ∼= ∠R, then ∠P > ∠R.

d. If ∠P < ∠Q and ∠Q < ∠R, then ∠P < ∠R.

can someone help me put this in context

Comment: (Do NOT use) measurement means graphical solution?

Comment: What is your definition of right, acute and obtuse angles?

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi it means not to use a certain theorem

Comment: @Arthur right angle = 90 degrees acute less than 90 and obtuse more than 90

Comment: @Arthur i cant figure out where each one belongs too ugh!

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi The fact that angles can be measured (by angles or radians) in a consistent way is far from a trivial result, and this problem is supposed to be solved by simpler means. MGeometry: if right, obtuse and acute angles are defined relative to $90^\circ$, you've already used measure. Don't you have other definitions?

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi they should be on the link i attached which are the axioms of congruence

Comment: @MGeometry The hint I've provided proves the claim. $∠CBD$ can be acute, obtuse or right angle. You'll get contradiction when you assume $∠CBD$ is obtuse or right

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi I have to prove it by using contradiction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $∠ABC=180^o=∠ABD+∠CBD$

Since $∠ABD$ is obtuse, $∠ABD>90^o$

**Case I**: $∠CBD>90^o$

$∠ABC=∠ABD+∠CBD>90^o+90^o=180^o$

which is a contradictiona as $∠ABC$ is a straight line angle.

**Case II**: $∠CBD=90^o$

$∠ABC=∠ABD+∠CBD=∠ABD+90^o>90^o+90^o=180^o$

which is a contradictiona as $∠ABC$ is a straight line angle.

You could alse see that in the photo below

[image]

Comment: How do I prove it tho I am not supposed to be using that

Comment: You **have** to use that since you are supposed to **know** this. Along with the hint you gave. Given $ABD>90^o$. Case I: Suppose $CBD=90^o$. Then $ABD+CBD>180^o$ which contradicts the above relation which is true (do you know why?). Do the same for case II

Comment: Wouldn't that be using the mesurement theorem since I'm adding the angles ?

Comment: could you tell me the answer Im just stuck on it

Comment: @MGeometry: I edited accordingly